# Conditional Min/Max

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Using excel 2010, how do I calculate min or max for column A, when it needs to take the value of column B into consideration?

So my table looks like this

```
Amt Spent   Quintile 

545,40      Q1

2146,41     Q1

 753,66     Q2

 821,11     Q2


 2157,99    Q3

 718,06     Q3

 526,58     Q4

 1047,50    Q4

 2009,30    Q5

 824,99     Q5
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the Maximum for quintile `"Q1"`:

```
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, A:A*(B:B="Q1"), 1)
```

To get the Minimum for quintile `"Q1"`:

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, A:A/(B:B="Q1"), 1)
```

You can also place a cell reference in place of the hard-coded constant `"Q1"`. i.e.

```
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, A:A *(B:B=B2), 1)
```